# Bulk upload data into data store for GAE Java project

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to populate the data store. Yet all the examples and instructions for populating the data store are concerned with Python projects. Is there a way to upload bulk data using the AppEngine Java tools? (At the moment the data is in CSV format, but I can easily reformat the data as needed.)

It would be especially useful if it could be done within the Eclipse IDE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same problem as you with this one.  According to the discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/72f58c28433cac26 
there's no equivalent tool available for Java yet. However it looks like there's nothing stopping you from using the Python tool to just populate the datastore and then accessing that data as normal through your Java code, although this assumes you're comfortable with Python, which could be the problem.

Comment: I am comfortable with python, was using the GAE plugins in Eclipse and was hoping for a more integrated tool. However, obviously this is the best interim solution -- thanks.